# Removed HalfWidth and Fullwidth spaces regex

Tags: regex, trim, appian

I have this regex code that removes leading and trailing white spaces.

```
regexreplaceall("^\s+|\s+$", ri!value, "")
```

However, it only removes halfwidth spaces.

Sample result process:

a) value(consist of half width spaces): `" he llo "`

```
   result: "he llo" -> correct
```

b) value(consist of fullwidth spaces): `"　　he llo　　"`

```
   result: "　　he llo　　" -> incorrect
```

Does anyone know whats the regex code for fullwidth spaces?
Im Using Appian platform

Thank You everyone!

Comment: Can you share the API reference? What is the regex flavor here? If it is Java, add `(?U)` at the pattern start.

Comment: Im using appian platform

Comment: So, adding the `(?U)` works, right?

Comment: I just added it right now and it works. Thankssss You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `\s` (and other) shorthand character class Unicode-aware.

Since [Appian uses](https://community.appian.com/b/appmarket/posts/regular-expression-functions) Java regex flavor, all you need is add the [`(?U)` embedded flag option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) to the pattern:

```java
regexreplaceall("(?U)^\s+|\s+$", ri!value, "")
```